# Background image cut off

Tags: css

Please have a look at this page: http://www.1001locaties.nl/beachclub-the-sunset-1993

As you can see the background is cut off. I don't know where in the CSS things are going wrong...

Comment: Your link is sending us to an error page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need a

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

after your footer div.

Comment: Thanks, that fixes it for that page, but I notice now on the homepage the problem still occurs: http://www.1001locaties.nl, what can that be?

Comment: I cannot see any problem in either IE, Chrome or Firefox. Have you managed to fix it? With floated elements, you need to clear the floats in order for the wrapping div to enclose the floated elements.

Comment: On the homepage, when I look at the bottom (resolution 1600x1200) the background does not go all the way to the bottom. So the Copyright notice, is not at the bottom of the page, but a little above that, which leaves a lot of whitespace underneath...

Comment: try dropping a `<div class="clearFloat"></div>` just before the closing of the `<div id="default-wrapper-body">` tag.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I was missing the closing tag for default-wrapper-body, so I added this: 
<div class="clearFloat"></div>
</div>

But still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `background-image: url('/images/bg_grey_white.jpg')` to the `<html>` tag.

You should add the background to the `<body>`, but the problem is that your body doesn't include the whole page.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to start off with a CSS-reset and go from there:
http://www.cssreset.com/

Also if you add the above you have to set margin: 0 auto to the html property.